# How to deactivate msgbox in a sub VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, subroutine, msgbox

```
Sub prelim()
    MsgboX "Hello World"
End Sub


Sub Main()
    Call prelim
End Sub
```

In the above code `Sub prelim` can't be edited.I want msgbox when I run `Sub prelim` but when I run `Sub Main` I don't want the message box to get popped out. How to do it?

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`
‘Your code here`
`Application.ScreenUpdating = True`

Comment: Try the above statement

Comment: Tried it.But it works only outside sub. When I run prelim I need msgbox  get prompted.But when I run main I dont need msgbox. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible without changing `Sub prelim`

```
Sub prelim(Optional silent As Boolean = True)
    If Not silent Then MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub


Sub Main()
    prelim True   'no msgbox
    prelim False  'with msgbox
    prelim        'no msgbx
End Sub
```

Comment: Worth noting that the `Call` keyword is no longer used. While it will compile fine, it is preferred to just do `prelim True` or `prelim`

Comment: @BrandonBarney Of course you are right! `Call` is deprecated.  I changed that.