# Updating associated value to an item selected from a comboBox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, updates

I have an excel sheet which contains two columns ( the column A contains Names and the column B contains Number Phones ).
I have created a comboBox with the list of names and I want to select a name from this comboBox and then update its corresponding phone number. I tried this code but it does not work.

```
Sub UpdateNumber()
Dim Ans As String, Index As Integer

Ans = InputBox("What is " & NameForm.ComboBox1.Value & " 's new phone number?")
If Ans <> "" Then 
    Index = NameForm.ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Sheets("Names").Range("A" & Index).Offset(0, 1).Value = Ans
       
End If
End Sub
```

Could someone help me, please ?

Comment: What does *Does not work* mean? Runtime error? Sheet is not updated? Wrong cell updated? Sub not called at all?

Comment: I think that the problem was with the sub because after choosing the name from the ComboBox and clicking on the update phone number button, nothing is happening !

Comment: did you add `call UpdateNumber` instruction to this "update phone number button" onclick event?

Comment: @Tomasz yes, I called it

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
Sub UpdateNumber(Optional boxShow As Boolean = True)
Dim Ans As String, Index As Integer

If boxShow = false Then exit sub
Ans = InputBox("What is " & NameForm.ComboBox1.Value & " 's new phone number?")
If Ans <> "" Then 
    Index = NameForm.ComboBox1.ListIndex
    Sheets("Names").Range("A" & Index).Offset(0, 1).Value = Ans
       
End If
End Sub

sub btn_onclick()
     boxShow True   'no msgbox
     boxShow False  'with msgbox
     boxShow 'no msgbx

end sub
```

found [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46115555/deactivate-msgbox-in-a-sub-vba)